# How does hangfire retry works in reccuringjob?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I have used recurring job of Hangfire to do my long process with cron expression of every minute (so basically it runs every minute to fetch data in db and do some processing) and I used Hangfire implementation retry of 3 when it fails.

Questions :

- How does retry works inside Hangfire? Does recurring job every minute and the retry will run in parallel?
- and how would I know if the retry of 3 is already done or reached already (In code)?

The reason why I want to know if the retry is already reached because I need to do something with my data in my database being processed by recurring job of Hangfire.

Note : Viewing dashboard to find out retry is not my option here but through code. Is it possible?

Implementation :

```
public class HangfireImpl
    {
        public static void ConfigureHangfire(IAppBuilder app, string dashBoardName, string connectionString)
        {
            GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new AutomaticRetryAttribute { Attempts = 3 });
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                    .UseSqlServerStorage(connectionString)
                    .UseDashboardMetric(SqlServerStorage.ActiveConnections)
                    .UseDashboardMetric(SqlServerStorage.TotalConnections)
                    .UseDashboardMetric(DashboardMetrics.FailedCount);

            app.UseHangfireDashboard(string.Format(@"/{0}", dashBoardName));
            app.UseHangfireServer();
        }

        public static void InitializeJobs()
        {
            // is there a way to find out how many retry occured inside my service.Execute?
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<Worker>(service => service.Execute(), Cron.Minutely);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I may already solve my own problems.

Questions :

> How does retry works inside Hangfire? Does recurring job every minute
>   and the retry will run in parallel?

I guess the answer is **YES** as long as their is available worker to execute your job.

> and how would I know if the retry of 3 is already done or reached
>   already (In code)?

I implemented JobFilterAttribute and  IElectStateFilter and register it using global filter of hangfire :

```
public class JobStateFilter : JobFilterAttribute , IElectStateFilter 
{
     public void OnStateElection(ElectStateContext context)
     {
          var failedState = context.CandidateState as FailedState;

           if (failedState == null) return;

          // I capture failed context here after 3 retry              
     }
}

GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new JobStateFilter());
```